# Has and Have grammar question

Tags: grammar

I saw the following sentence in my workbook:"How many friends does the author have?" Shouldn't it be "has" instead of "have" for singular pronoun? And the answer should use "has" as well: "The author has 2 friends."

Comment: Hello Muuu Mu,  this question has been asked and answered before.  In summary,  the tense and singular/plural is in the auxiliary verb "does".  The verb "have" is a bare infinitive and doesn't change to agree with the subject or for tense.  Does he have/ Do you have / Did he have / Did you have etc.

Comment: @JamesK you are quite right, of course. I was a bit distracted and confused when I wrote that and have hence deleted it. Apologies to the OP.